# HTML integration of image URI for validation

Tags: html, w3c-validation, data-uri

I have a problem with validation of my site with, mainly because of data/images base64 URIs.

Here is the diagnostic of https://html5.validator.nu/

> Error: Malformed byte sequence: e9.
> At line 2, column 259

(etc.)

As for https://validator.w3.org/ it simply says it cannot analyze the site.

What I have in my website is:

```html
<a class=imgfr onclick='toggle("fr")' title=Fran&ccedil;ais>
<img class=imfr 
src="data:image/png,base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAUCAIAAAAVyRqTAAAAjklEQVQ4jWM4cupJy7Qz2NGsM0+evfny6QsIfcMgHz15MqnnTV8LdnTqCEPLrCMsRnNwoSv33vz59wc7unbljpIIGPFgkkDTGYCuo8xoLOYCSaCHRl09VFytNurqUVcPpKuxG00VV2MPkGHpah4zylwNqsBmHQFXV5gkuAL79gU7glVgQPIJuNJCZgArMAD4cQgh3IjAhAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" 
title=Francais alt=Fran&ccedil;ais>
</a>
```

The document is declared as only

```html
<!Doctype html>
```

I have in the `head`:

```html
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>
```

Obviously I have checked several Q/A here like [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images) or [How to display Base64 images in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html), however these do not provide the answers to my question.

Also the one validator which works tells me that my `http-equiv` below have bad value attribute:

```html
<meta http-equiv="window-target" content="_top">
<meta http-equiv=Expires content="Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT">
<meta http-equiv=Pragma content="no-cache must-revalidate">
```

What should I do?

Comment: In order to reply to a comment which does not show anymore (???) the colon and no-space were there , it was my mistake in copying... Also, although the validator tells me that my attribute value for http-equiv are invalid, we can find lots of resources on the web which tell differently : http://cristian.sulea.net/blog.php?p=2014-01-14-disable-browser-caching-with-meta-html-tags or https://wp-mix.com/disable-caching-html/  for instance tell it is correct....

Answer (score 0):

Some things were my mistakes... I did not read precisely enough the diagnostic of the w3c evaluator.

The diagnosis

> Error malformed sequence

was ***not*** related to the images URI as I thought, but to accented characters

Secondly, I received advice on another forum that, although there are a good number of blogs and books and so on which support/advertise on following the advice of inserting the meta tags I mentioned in the original post, as they are not recommended anymore - even worse, they are altogether discarded in the HTML as of last year at the minimum - I should better follow the norm, even if some discussions are still ongoing.